# Como corregir examen multiple choise

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de examenes multiple choise con php y mysql (una pregunta puede tener 1 o varias respuestas correctas).

El problema que estoy teniendo es a la hora de corregir el examen, no se como hacerlo. ¿Alquien puede darme una idea en cuanto a la mecanica que podria utilizar?.

Habia pensado en ir haciendo consultas sql por cada respuesta que se marco como correcta para verificar si es asi, pero tiene dos inconvenientes:

1- No me devolveria lo que espero, ya que evalua la respuesta independientemente y una pregunta puede tener mas de 1 respuesta correcta.

2- No me parece que sea lo mas optimo.

Tengo 1 tabla para las preguntas (Id,id_examen, pregunta) y otra tabla para las respuestas (Id, id_examen, id_pregunta, respuesta, correcta).

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posibilidad sería, usando jQuery, almacenar en un arreglo el id de cada pregunta y sus respuestas, y luego compararlas con las respuestas correctas en la base de datos.

Te muestro un ejemplo con una sola pregunta, pero si capturas la idea, lo puedes extender a varias preguntas teniendo al final del examen un botón que jQuery recibiría para hacer un recorrido obteniendo los ids de cada pregunta y sus respuestas, enviarías ese formulario serializado por POST a un archivo PHP que se encargaría de enviar **una sola consulta a la bd** que haga la comparación de las respuestas dadas con las respuestas correctas y devuelva la calificación del exámen.

Lo puedes hacer perfectamente **con un solo click en el formulario de examen, con una consulta SQL que además te devolvería el resultado**, claro para eso debes capturar los datos en un arreglo, enviarlos a la BD y que el diseño de la misma tenga un sistema de validación de las respuestas correctas.

Es sólo una idea, pensada así, rápido. Quizá alguien proponga algo mejor.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#r1').click(function() {
    var respuesta = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
      respuesta[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(respuesta);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Examen</h1>
<p><b>1.  ¿Quiénes han sido presidentes de los EE UU?</b></p>
<input name="r1_selector[]" id="r11_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />Barack Obama <br />
<input name="r1_selector[]" id="r12_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />Michael Jackson <br />
<input name="r1_selector[]" id="r13_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />Ronald Reagan <br />
<input name="r1_selector[]" id="r14_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />Fidel Castro <br />
<input type="button" id="r1" name="r1_n" value="Validar Respuesta 1" />
```

**Nota:**

> Pensándolo con un poco más de calma, podrías incluso tener en tu base de datos una tabla llamada `examenes` en la cual tienes una serie de exámenes con las respuestas correctas. Esos exámenes estarían identificados por un `id`.

Enviarías por post a otro archivo PHP un arreglo con todas las respuestas recogidas en el `examen`, supongamos que dicho examen tiene el `id=1`, luego pides a la BD un arreglo que tendrías ya definido con las respuestas correctas de cada pregunta para ese examen determinado y haces una comparación a nivel de programa entre las respuestas correctas y las preguntas, acumulando la puntuación.

Es que la pregunta es un poco amplia. Por ejemplo, el sistema de puntuación lleva su trabajo y su lógica, pues si en una pregunta de selección múltiple en la que hay dos posibilidades de buena respuesta el alumno responde solamente una correctamente, la puntuación (imagino), no sería la misma que si responde bien a los dos preguntas o si responde mal a todas.

Para completar lo que sería un posible proyecto, por orden:

#### (a). Archivo PHP/HTML con el examen en un formulario

```
<h1>Examen</h1>
<form id="examen" action="examinar.php" method="post">
     <p><b>1.  ¿Quiénes han sido presidentes de los EE UU?</b></p>
     <input name="r1_selector[]" id="r11_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />Barack Obama <br />
     <input name="r1_selector[]" id="r12_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />Michael Jackson <br />
     <input name="r1_selector[]" id="r13_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />Ronald Reagan <br />
     <input name="r1_selector[]" id="r14_check" class="r_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />Fidel Castro <br />

    ... más preguntas

    <input type="button" id="btn_validar" name="r1_n" value="Validar Examen" />
</form>

<div id="resultado">Aquí se mostrará el resultado final del examen</div>
```

#### (b). jQuery que se lanza al pulsar el botón **Validar** del formulario

Este sería un ejemplo de función Ajax/jQuery para postear datos de un formulario:

```
//Aquí se escucha el click del botón validar, 
// se recogen los datos y se pasan a la función `post_data()`
$( "#btn_validar" ).click(function(e) 
{
    var data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    //Se pueden agregar otros valores al arreglo si se quiere 
    data.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value, name: "examinar", value:"examinar" });
    e.preventDefault();
    post_data(data) ;
});

//Esta función recibe el arreglo y hace el post
function post_data(data) 
{
    var frm=$( "#examen" );
    var request = $.ajax
        ({
            url: frm.attr("action"), //archivo php indicado en el atributo action del form
            method: frm.attr('method'), //tipo de método indicado en el form
            data: data, //datos obtenidos del form
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function( msg ) 
        {
            $( "#resultado" ).html( msg );
            return msg;
            console.log(msg);
            //alert (msg);

        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
        {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });

}
```

#### c. Archivo PHP que procesa en background las respuestas del examen

```
if(isset($_POST['examinar']))
{
    //LLamada a la BD pidiendo las respuestas del examen 1
    //Comparar respuestas
    //Enviar nota final como respuesta
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Cedano, te comento que entiendo perfectamente lo que dices, solo me quedan una duda, ¿como comparo el array que genero con jQuery con la respuesta de la BD?. Gracias!

Comment: Como te comentaba, digamos que todo el examen está contenido en un formulario y tiene un botón llamado por ejemplo `Validar`. Al hacer clic en ese botón lanzas una función de jQuery que serializa todo el formulario y lo envía a **otro archivo php** el cual se encarga de procesar el examen de una forma totalmente transparente para el usuario. Ese otro archivo es el que se encarga de enviar las respuestas a la BD y obtener el resultado final del examen, devolviéndolo a la página desde la cual se envió el formulario con las respuestas.  Ver:  [post en jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Gracias Cedano nuevamente por tu ayuda, te cuento que tengo todo como vos me lo sugeris, donde estoy teniendo dudas ahora es en el "C" el archivo PHP,  hago la llamada a la BD pidiendo las respuestas, pero como comparo los resultados de la BD con el array?. Espero me puedas ayudar en este ultimo punto. Gracias!!

Comment: Sugeriría que, llegado a este punto plantearas una nueva pregunta sobre cómo comparar dos arrays: el del formulario con las respuestas y el de la BD. Creo que así podrías tener más respuestas interesantes de otros usuarios y optar por la que más te convenga. Por otra parte la filosofía de SO es responder a una pregunta en específico. Empezar a explicar la forma de comparar los dos arrays creo que da lugar a una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Otra opción que se me ocurre y podría ser interesante sería la siguiente : tener en tu BD una tabla auxiliar que devuelva la puntuación de cada pregunta enviándole un algoritmo de comparación. No es mala idea ya que tendrías un modelo de datos completo en la BD. La tabla auxiliar compararía las diferentes posibilidades de cualquier respuesta y devolvería una puntuación. Ejemplo: 0 si todas mal, 2.5 si una correcta y otra no, 5 si las dos correctas. De ese modo evaluarías  cualquier respuesta de cualquier examen y de cualquier pregunta recibiendo al mismo tiempo la puntuación total.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio muchisimo!. Ahora realizo la nueva pregunta.

Comment: Es un proyecto interesante para cualquier centro de estudios. Podrías tener una tabla exámenes con las preguntas de forma que el mismo formulario de examen y las posibles respuestas serían cargados desde la BD. Se puede hasta tener una tabla preguntas y crear exámenes aleatorios , y el estudiante podría tener un registro de exámenes / respuestas. Un registro general o parcial de calificaciones, etc.  En fin con un buen modelo de BD se podría hacer todo con más facilidad.

Comment: Sisi, asi lo tengo. Una variedad de preguntas y respuestas, el sistema escoje al azar las preguntas en forma aleatorias y desordenadas, como asi tambien las respuestas.... bastante interesante pero trabajoso, je

Comment: Parece trabajoso pero luego facilita todo. Por ejemplo ya no tendrías que elaborar un récord de notas general del estudiante o las calificaciones a final de curso. Ya tienes todo en la BD. Y no te digo nada para estadísticas , promedios, etc. Yo me inventaría un algoritmo de validación y clasificación de preguntas. Hasta podrías hacer estadísticas en base a preguntas por ejemplo determinar en una materia cual es la pregunta más difícil de todas, aquella en la que más han fallado la totalidad de alumnos...

Comment: Esxcelentes ideas!! muchas graciasss... si ire ampliando el proyecto, por ahora necesito que corrija JA, por cierto ya publique la nueva pregunta por si tenes alguna idea jeje: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68121/como-comprar-array-con-resultado-de-bd

Comment: Interesante proyecto. Yo empecé uno para Escuela parroquial pero no me dio tiempo de terminarlo. Ahora tengo que irme cuando pueda revisaré la nueva pregunta. Aunque aquí hay gente mucho más capaz que yo y seguro tendrás buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Ah ok Gracias!!